# No Cucumber tests run in a simplified Spring Boot 5.7+ JDK17 and JUnit 5 environment

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Can you help getting this most simple Cucumber test run in a the simplified Spring Boot 2.5, JDK17, JUnit 5 environment? I tried all kinds of solutions without any result.

You can find a minimal github repo in [this github project](https://github.com/johan974/cucumber-springboot-junit5).

The error message is (without executing any tests):

> [ERROR] feb. 11, 2022 12:44:05 P.M. org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters
> loadClasspathResource
>
> [ERROR] INFO: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource
> [file:/K:/A__IntelliJ_projects/spring-boot-cucumbertests/target/test-classes/junit-platform.properties].

Pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.7</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>nl.tester.springboot.cucumbertests</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The exclusions are pretty complex. Have you tried on a recent version of spring boot and without out the exclusions.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Just see below, I already found an answer. And yes, most of the exclusions can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right list of test packages:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>nl.tester.springboot.cucumbertests</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```